# Using Caliburn Micro in class library

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a class library which contains several user controls. This library uses caliburn micro to bind the `UserControl`s to their corresponding `ViewModels` using `x:Name` approach in the same class library.

Now I have an host application which hosts these UserControls in a Window. But this host application doesn't use Caliburn Micro at all. Then how can I initialize caliburn bootstrapper in the library itself.

**HostApplication:**

```
<Window>       
  <ContentControl>
       <library:MainUserControl DataContext="{Binding MainUserControlViewModel}"/>
  </ContentControl>
</Window>
```

**Class Library**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainUserControl">
   <ContentControl x:Name="OtherUserControlInSameLibrary"/>
</UserControl>
```

I tried to inherit Bootstrapper base class like `AppBootstrapper: Bootstrapperbase` and passing `false` to constructor parameter `useApplication`. And then I called `Initialize()` method. But still conventions are not applied.

**MainUserControlViewModel Constructor**

```
public MainUserControlViewModel()
{            
     AppBootstrapper appBootstrapper = new AppBootstrapper();
     appBootstrapper.Initialize();
     if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLog(type);            
}
```

**BootstrapperBase override**

```
 public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        public AppBootstrapper():base(false)
        {
        }
    }
```

I also tried to run caliburn debugger but nothing is showed in my output window.

Comment: [Feedback from CAL mantainers](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/241)

Answer (score 0):

Putting together the mentioned [feedback](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/241) by Caliburn.Micro mantainers and [this blog post](http://www.andyrace.com/2014/05/caliburn-micro-and-usercontrols.html) by Andy Race, it seems somehow it is doable, but the client application code has still to reference CM as well.

Apart from other needed settings (see references), the constraint is due to how the custom control view-model is bound to its view stated in XAML: the only way is to explicitly set the view-model by means of `cal:Bind.Model`.

```xml
...
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Control.Library;assembly=Control.Library" 
...
<controls:SomeControlView 
    cal:Bind.Model="Control.Library.SomeControlViewModel" />
```

For the rest, the client application can totally ignore Caliburn.Micro.